# Very confusing output on my C program

Tags: c, io, runtime-error

This days I posted some more questions related to that problem. Only that now I got something really interesting.

Look my code:

```
#include <libpq-fe.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LINE_SIZE 100

PGconn *connect(char *);

int main() 
{
    connect("/path/to/file.props");
    return 0;
}

PGconn *connect(char *file_path) 
{
    const char **keywords;
    const char **values;
    char *line = malloc(LINE_SIZE);
    char *prop, *val, *tmp;
    int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
    PGconn *conn = NULL;
    FILE *creds = fopen(file_path, "r");
    
    if (creds == NULL) {
        perror("error: cannot open credentials file");   //!!! warning
        exit(1);
    }
    
    keywords = malloc(6 * sizeof(char *));
    values = malloc(6 * sizeof(char *));
    
    while (fgets(line, LINE_SIZE, creds) != NULL) {
        if (line[strlen(line) - 1] == '\n')
            line[strlen(line) - 1] = '\0';
        prop = line;
        while(*(prop++) != '=') {
            i++;
        }
        tmp = prop;
        prop = malloc(i + 1);
        strncpy(prop, line, i);
        prop[i] = '\0';
        keywords[j++] = prop;
        val = malloc(strlen(line) - strlen(prop) + 1);
        strcpy(val, tmp);
        values[k++] = val;
        i = 0;
    }
    keywords[j] = NULL;
    values[k] = NULL;
    printf("%s %s %s %s %s\n", keywords[0], keywords[1], keywords[2], keywords[3], keywords[4]);
    printf("%s %s %s %s %s\n", values[0], values[1], values[2], values[3], values[4]); //prints well
    conn = PQconnectdbParams(keywords, values, 0);
    if (PQstatus(conn) != CONNECTION_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", PQerrorMessage(conn));
        exit(1);
    }
    
    return conn;
}
```

When I run it I get the following output:

> hostaddr port user password dbname
>
> 127.0.0.1 5432 my_user my_password my_db
>
> error: cannot open credentials file: Bad address

As you can see, the file content is printed, and only after its content is printed, the error above (from line with "warning" comment) is printed like that file cannot be read.

Do you have any idea about what can happen here?

Comment: You have at least one memory leak, don't allocate `line` of the heap when a normal array will work just as fine. And of course the `keywords` and `values` "arrays".

Comment: `perror( file_path )` produces a much more useful error message.  Rather than attempting to describe the file, just give the path.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg `strncpy` issue is resolved in `if` block under while. The file that is read contains 5 lines key value pairs with = sign between them.

Comment: Without `PQconnextdbParams` is the behavior the same?

Comment: I recommend you step through the code line by line in a debugger.

Comment: @WilliamPursell if I change to `perror(file_path)`, I get a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error.

Comment: @artaxerxe: `creds` becomes surely an invalid pointer (perhaps null).

Comment: @Kirilenko no. Than it runs ok.

Comment: SideNote: This: `val = malloc(strlen(line) - strlen(prop) + 1);`, should just be this: `val = malloc(strlen(tmp)+1);`

Comment: @WhozCraig A better approach. Thanks! :)

Comment: @artaxerxe: If you get a segmentation fault with such a trivial change (the `perror(file_path)`) one), then your problem lie elsewhere...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"connect" is a system call to connect to a socket. I assume that PQconnextdbParams might try to use "connect" and is directed to your function again. Try to rename the function to "myconnect".

Comment: Yes, this sounds reasonable: +1. Anyhow, the OP should have got warnings regarding duplicate symbols, or mismatching types. The latter dueing to the fact that the `connect()` system call's signature is fully different form the OP's `connect()`.

Comment: @alk: Not it the declaration of system `connect()` is not `#included` in this translation unit. The compiler has no way of knowing that there is such a function, and the dynamic linker will give preference to the executable version of the symbol over that from any shared library.